# Jquery to echo and append data into textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to use jQuery to echo text as it is typed, into a text area below the input line, and as it does, put random pre-selected words on the end of that repeated data. Each time a new letter is typed as input, I'd like some other "random" word appended each of the 3 "repeats", kind of a jumble.

```
Input= "true blue"

TextArea = 
true blue black<br/>
true blue car<br/>
true blue sock<br/>

If the input = "true blues"

TextArea =
true blues snake<br/>
true blues grass<br/>
true blues red<br/>
```

All new results because "s" was typed. (or as close to "new/random" as can be easily)

I'm going to have 200 words in an array, and with each key press I'd like the appended words to change (`onkeyup`?). If they can appear random or can be randomly picked from a larger list/file.

Input from the form is repeated for 3 lines in the text area, and 3 random words are also appended basically. Onkeypress echo input + random_word (x3).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting challenge.

I've played with it for a couple of hours and have come up with a rudimentary, inelegant attempt - brute force.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/8hrmA/)

JS

```
var spacecount = 0;
var sumcodes = 0;
var wordarray = 0;
var randword = ['gould','horowitz','bach','scarlatti','handel','vivaldi','corelli','albinoni','allegri','pinnock',];
$(function(){
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
        var char1 = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        $('#keycode').html(e.keyCode);
        $('#charcode').html(char1);
        $('#texthere').append(char1);
        sumcodes = sumcodes + e.keyCode;
        if (e.keyCode == 32)
          {
            spacecount=spacecount + 1;
            $('#spacecount').html(spacecount);
           }
        if (spacecount > 2)
          {
           spacecount = 0;
           wordarr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
           $('#texthere').append(randword[wordarr] + ' ');
           $('#sumcodes').html(sumcodes);
           sumcodes = 0;
           }
    });
});
```

The random number generator is not that robust. I tried to relate it to the sum of the ASCII character codes, but was unsuccessful (I'll play a bit more).

Comment: This is a very good start! Spaces for me seem to be the only way to append a word, but that's more than I had. I'll also mess with the fiddle to see if I can get it to do more of what I'm after. The randomness seems just fine to me, thanks for all of this so far! 
input= tree  |out= %input%pinmock, %input%bar, %input%foo
input= trees |out = %input%red, %input%qwerty, %input%car
Clear the textarea each keyup, and echo the cumulative input so far, and then append a word to the total input. Nonetheless I think I can make this work that way, thanks!